# Why roscore can' find the good IP adress?

Tags: roscore

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

My computer has two IPv4 adresses (one for the wired lan, one for the wifi). The computer name is gilgamesh. Its name on the wired lan is gilgamesh too. But its name through wifi is gilgamesh-wifi.
When I start roscore, with wifi on, it complains about not being able to ping gilgamesh (While it should try to ping gilgamesh-wifi).

How to specify the name of the host computer when launching roscore ? (or any ros server)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11151/why-roscore-can%27-find-the-good-ip-adress-?/) by [Guido](https://answers.ros.org/users/279/guido/) on ROS Answers with karma: 514 on 2011-09-08

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

set the ROS_HOSTNAME environment variable to the one you want.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2011-09-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Guido](https://answers.ros.org/users/279/guido/) on 2011-09-08**:
Thank you. It works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

try setting your ROS_MASTER_URI env variable to:
`ROS_MASTER_URI=http://gilgamesh-wifi:11311`

---

Originally posted by [JeffRousseau](https://answers.ros.org/users/75/jeffrousseau/) with karma: 1607 on 2011-09-08

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Guido](https://answers.ros.org/users/279/guido/) on 2011-09-08**:
Thank you, this works, but i'd rather use ROS_MASTER_URI when dealing with remote computer.